# How to edit a already inserted value in boost text_orachive?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

```
std::ostringstream oss;
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);
```

I add a int with value 0 at the start of the archive. This will act as a placeholder.

```
int number_of_objects= 0;
oa & number_of_objects;
```

I add some objects to a boost text_orachive.

```
//loop and select objects which fit criteria

oa & object[i];
```

Now how do I go back (seek) and put the actual value (i) in place of the placeholder (number_of_objects) in the serialized archive?

Comment: You don't. Tell us what you are trying to do. Because there's bound to be a far better solution.

Comment: depending on my selection criteria I add different number of objects on the server side, How will the client know how many objects has the server sent? so I want add this number of objects beforehand

Comment: Two options: send the actual count in advance. Otherwise: signal end of stream by way of (a) connection close (b) a sentinel value. This is network protocol 101

Comment: thanks, the second options seems perfect

Comment: It must be trivial to know the count in advance, since you are also storing the entire stream in a stringstream anyway. A network stream, by definition, doesn't allow a seek.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to *manually* create relative references inside your archive.

Boost Serialization comes with high-level support for cross-referencing object graphs.

I suggest you work through the samples, notably the ones using `shared_ptr` to see how you can benefit from the automatic support for internal references in archived objects in Boost Serialization.

Comment: sorry I couldnt understand you, could you explain in more detial please?

Comment: Not really. It might not be relevant after your other comments. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#examples for docs